# ng-sortable dragging item not visible. AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm using AngularJS ng-sortable to sort tabs. Everything is working fine but dragging item is not visible. While dragging an item is appending on the body but not visible.

Comment: Did you figure out why it was happening in your case?
Its happenning with my code as well

Comment: It works in the [demo](http://a5hik.github.io/ng-sortable/#/).  Can you post a [MCVE (or a minimum, complete, and verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your code so that your problem can be reproduced?